# I want to make a Final year engineering project in Blender. What is the scope of Blender?

Tags: documentation

I have been using Blender for a few months for animation and game development and am well versed with python scripting used in blender too.
I am a 3rd year engineering student and was thinking to make my final year project using Blender.

What all are the things exactly that Blender is capable of doing?
Can I make something useful(not recreational projects like games or animations) with Blender?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: You could do something practical. Like, write a plug in. I could realy use a comic book plug in. Something that help comic people create comics. So, things like building a character, posing tools and finally a panel maker for pages so poses can be done in each panel. After that, an a page exporter so that can be used as a reference for inking the page! Love to see that plug in. The reality is Blender does all this it's just a matter of making a work flow quicker by integrating into a plug in.

Comment: Take a look at Blender's [features](https://www.blender.org/features/) page.

Comment: This appears pretty broad. It might be useful to at least specify what kind of engineering you are doing and ask how blender can be used in that field.

Answer (score 4):

Blender can be used for geometry creation and visualization. The geometry can be manually entered or imported and manipulated using Python. Using Python, blender can interact with data in the real world. The cycles rendering engine implements ray tracing and can replicate optical behavior. There are several built in simulators, however they are intended for animation, not engineering. There are two different fluid simulators (Lattice-Boltzmann and SPH). There is a solid body simulator that includes mechanical constraints. The scripting capabilities make it straight forward to couple other simulations to Blender. Since Blender is open source you can access the source code and extend the built in simulators. From these basic capabilities many different engineering things can be done. The list below shows some places to look for ideas. Good luck!

- Visualization

  - [Scientific Visualization in Blender](https://www.cv.nrao.edu/%7Ebkent/blender/index.html)
  - [Post process CFD data](https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&v=5-GtdRLfeFI)
  - [Create and visualize "computational cell biology"](https://mcell.org/)
  - [Astronomical data](https://www.astroblend.com)
  - [Plotting data](https://github.com/zeffii/BlenderSciViz)
  - [Plotting functions](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47493/using-blender-for-plotting-graphs)
- Image processing
- Augmented reality
- [Particle Tracking  Velocimetry](https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&v=eJk-78r6lGM)
- [Real-time sensor visualization](https://www.blender.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=7723)
- [Psychology testing](https://blenderartists.org/t/psychology-suite-in-blender-advice-please/394866)
- [Engineering](https://web.archive.org/web/20150301061220/http://wiki.blender.org:80/index.php/Community:Science/Engineering)
- [Robotics](https://web.archive.org/web/20171108094305/https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Community:Science/Robotics),[more](http://www.cs.trinity.edu/%7Ejhowland/class.files.cs357.html/blender/blender-stuff/robot-blender.pdf)
- [Real-time audio spectrum visualization](https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?390591-real-time-audio-frequency-spectrum)
- [3D Printing](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35415/why-is-blender-so-popular-for-3d-printing)
- [Automotive design at Tata](https://www.blender.org/user-stories/mathilde-ampe-automotive-design-with-blender/)
- [Dental appliance design](https://github.com/patmo141/odc_public/wiki)
- [Design a fixture for spinal surgery](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70517/creating-an-implant-for-spinal-surgery-workflow-questions/70541)
- [Aerodynamic geometry case preparation for CFD](https://mantiumcae.com/new-car-for-kvrc-using-optimization-methods-with-caeses-and-blender/)
- [CFD visualization](https://www.blendernation.com/2011/11/22/oak-ridge-national-laboratory-blender-on-a-supercomputer/)
- [Industrial fire simulation](https://www.blender.org/conference/2016/presentations/234)
- [Simulation sensor imaging](https://download.blender.org/documentation/bc2012/maciej-murakowski.pdf)
- [Thermal radiation shielding design](https://plus.google.com/116913296788529614260/posts/ZQXr1w82J51)
- [Structure solar radiation simulation](https://www.e3s-conferences.org/articles/e3sconf/pdf/2016/05/e3sconf_seed2016_00027.pdf)
- [Simulate soil optical properties](https://www.spiedigitallibrary.org/journals/optical-engineering/volume-54/issue-10/104102/Soil-signature-simulation-in-the-thermal-infrared/10.1117/1.OE.54.10.104102.full?SSO=1), [more](https://www.cis.rit.edu/%7Ecnspci/references/carson2015b.pdf)
- [Synthetic aperture radar simulation](https://digitalcommons.calpoly.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?referer=&httpsredir=1&article=1364&context=theses)
- ... and lots more